# how to create and save windows form from another form at runtime in .net

Tags: c#

I want to create and **save** a windows form with **some controls** from another windows form.
I tried below code but it's only create a new form with a textbox at runtime but i am not able to save this form in same solution path.

```
using (Form form = new Form())
            {
                form.Text = "About Us";
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                form.Controls.Add(tb);                    
                form.ShowDialog();
            }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?